# Disable auto generation of URL in Grails

Tags: grails

Grails always provides URL for every method in a `Controller`. For example, if there's a method `branch()` in controller `repository`, there would be automatically a URL for `localhost:8080/project/repository/branch`.

What I want is to disable this. So unless I declare that URL to `URLMappings.groovy`, accessing this webpage will render a 404 Error, even this `Controller/method` exists.

I'm using `Grails` 2.4.4 by the way.

Comment: You shouldn't have public methods in controllers which are not actions, this is against a convention. Either make those methods protected/private or make code more object oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove this code, from your **UrlMappings**:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" {
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
}
```

Now you will get 404 if you haven't declared mapping for each action.